# Getting around error 520 in python using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to crawl the website https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/wheelchairs/, but when i print the html script I get error 520. I understand I would have to add headers and use session to get 200, but I'm really confused how I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

The status code `520` means that there was no problem with your request - the `5**` means that it was the server-side problem, in that specific example the `520` status code is also named as `unknown error`